# How can i use Dagger2 and CursorLoader

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm not familiar with Dagger2 and now i want to give it a try. 
So far everything is going as far as excepted.

Now i want to use CursorLoader within my fragment and (of course) i have a problem to inject my database in my ContentProvider. So far I can inject everything within the calling class but now i don't know where to inject my dbHelper class. Here the two snippets where i'm get a NPE.

```
// My Fragment code... works fine
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new CursorLoader(getContext(), CategoriesProvider.uriCategories(),
            CategoryContract.CATEGORIE_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
}
```

Within my ContentProvider i want to inject the DBHelper class...

```
@Inject
public CategoriesProvider(DBHelper dbHelper) {
    this.dbHelper = dbHelper;
}
```

I don't know how to make the connection between the two elements..
Hope you understand me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to how `Activity`s and `Service`s (and sometimes `Fragment`s) are created by the framework, you can't use constructors injection with `ContentProvider`s. If you add a `void inject(CategoriesProvider categoriesProvider);` method to your `@Component`, then in your `CategoriesProvider.onCreate()` method you can obtain your component and call `component.inject(this);`.

It's worth noting that the `Application` class does not get initialized until after `ContentProvider`s do, so if your `@Component` is held in your `Application`, I believe that `getContext().getApplicationContext()` would return `null`. See this issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8727.